# Android Widget Refresh

Tags: android, widget, onupdate

I have implemented a widget but have problems refreshing it.
I get the initial onUpdate , and again if I leave it for ages.

However I want changes in my main application to be automatically reflected on the widget.
How do I get that to refresh ?
Is there a way of calling the widget from my Activity (do I just do a static routine) or is there a way I can force my "onUpdate" to be called each time the phone returns back to the home screen ?

Comment: Don't assume your widget will be on the home screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you implement your widget using a service to update the RemoteViews? If so you can kick off that service with an Intent and the widget will update.

```
Intent widgetUpdateIntent = new Intent(context, MyClassName.UpdateService.class);
context.startService(widgetUpdateIntent );
```

Comment: I am not sure how I would setup a service within the widget to service the remote views. Is there an example you can point me at ?

Comment: Is it not possible to have my application activity send an event to the widget to refresh ?

Comment: Finally got it, you meant have a service update the widget and then I can call the service from anywhere. Did that - works a treat, thanks !

Comment: Great, if it is solved can you close this question please by clicking the 'tick'. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager//.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 500, 2, pendingIntent1);
.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 500, pendingIntent1);
```